# How to check GKE patch update release notes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We are using GKE Stable channel. GKE patch updates release regularly.

But Patch version fix details is not available.
https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/security-bulletins
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes-stable

We don't know what updated in patch versions.

For patch version 1.21.12-gke.1500,details present in [security bulletins](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/security-bulletins#gcp-2022-016) .
But for patch versions 1.21.12-gke.1700 ,1.21.12-gke.2200 fix details is not available.

So we could not able to confirm the impact of the update.

Is there any proper way to check the GKE patch version update detail?